# png file inside drawable folder naming: characters admitted

Tags: android, android-drawable

I would know if spaces, dots, numbers and underscore characters are admitted for naming a png graphical resources inside drawable folder.
For example, this filenames:

- image name.png
- image.name.png
- image name.name.png
- image_001.png
- image_001 name.png

are valid?

Answer (score 4):

Only the ones with underscores are valid, because every resource name becomes a key in the generated R class like e.g. R.drawable.image_name. I think from there it is not hard to see why dots and spaces would not work well.

Answer (score 0):

Spaces, dashes and other chars are not supported by Android, so these are the ways you can name images in the **drawable** folder:

- imagename.png
- image_name.png
- image_001.png
- image_001_name.png